# kotlin kotest/kotlintest BehaviorSpec afterSpec/finalizeSpec called too often or not at all

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, kotlintest, kotest

I have a kotlin kotest (formerly known as kotlintest) BehaviorSpec

with one `Given("...")` and many `When("...") Then("...")` under it

I want to execute a cleanup after the whole Spec (respectively every `Given` clause) has finished.

```
    @MicronautTest
    class StructurePersistSpec(
            private val iC : InstancesC
    ) : BehaviorSpec({
    
        // afterSpec {
        finalizeSpec {
            cleanup()
        }

        Given("...") {
            When("...") {
                Then("...") {
                ...
                }
                Then("...") {
                ...
                }
            }
            When("...") {
                Then("...") {
                ...
                }
                Then("...") {
                ...
                }
            }
        }   
   ...
   }
```

on using `afterSpec { }` I get **multiple calls** (amount of `When`s??) to the `afterSpec { }` clause and NOT just one after the Spec finished (or finishing of the/each `Given` Clause)

on using `finalizeSpec { }` it does NOT get called at all (breakpoint inside it is never hit)

what am I doing wrong?

or did I miss some fancy characteristics of `BehaviorSpec`s ?

Comment: Did you override the `IsolationMode` in your project/test configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting multiple calls is that probably you have set a different `IsolationMode` for your test.

That would mean your Spec will be recreated (and then cleaned) for every test. In order to have a single `afterSpec` call from the framework, your `IsolationMode` must be set to `SingleInstance`.

Bare in mind that might affect the way your tests are being executed hence their validity or ability to pass.

Documentation: https://kotest.io/isolation_mode/